# How do I hide my Wicket markup files from direct access when being stored in the webapp folder

Tags: web-applications, wicket

While it does help in organizing my project, placing my Wicket markup in the web app folder exposes those files to direct access by sub-amateur hackers and typowriters.

However, this example project has managed to thwart my amateurish attempts at accessing the raw markup file.

http://examples-wickettutorial.rhcloud.com/markupfolder/

So tell me how does one place Wicket markup in the web app folder while preventing unwanted access to them from the Internet.

Comment: Well, why are putting your markup in the web app folder in the first place? The wep app folder exists to make something accessible 'from the internet'.

Comment: Well, the thing is that the online example has managed to idiot-proof itself, whereas when I try the same example on my local machine, it isn't idiot-proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in WEB-INF folder. It's purpose is exactly for that use case.

Comment: WEB-INF is a possible solution. But I want to know why I get a 404 on the URL (http://examples-wickettutorial.rhcloud.com/markupfolder/markupFolder/org/wicketTutorial/HomePage.html). But when I try the same example on my local machine and go to a similar URL(http://localhost:8080/CustomFolder4MarkupExample/markupFolder/org/wicketTutorial/HomePage.html) I get a blank page whose source is that of the raw markup file.

Comment: Your url was wrong! Try with: http://examples-wickettutorial.rhcloud.com/markupFolder/org/wicketTutorial/markupfolder/HomePage.html